# degree of the differential equation $\left(\left(\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}\right)^2 + e^x\right)^2= 1+\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider following 3rd order differential equation,
$\left(\left(\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}\right)^2 + e^x\right)^2= 1+\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} \tag1$
In order to find the degree we can expand the left-hand side.
$\left(\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}\right)^4 + (e^x)^2 +2\left(\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}\right)^2e^x = 1+\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}\tag2$
Then there are two exponents we can take from the highest differential coefficient which is 4 and 2. The definition we are given for the degree states only to "take the exponent of the highest differential coefficient when the equation is a polynomial in all differential coefficients". Which do we define as the degree of this differential equation?

Comment: You may as well define $f=y''$ and so the equation becomes $$((f')^2 + e^x)^2 = 1 + f$$

Comment: You mean the "highest order differential quotient"? And the equation has to be "polynomial in all differential quotients"? There is no further qualification on the dependence on $x$ of all other parameters?

Comment: The degree is 4. yes, need to set it up as polynomial first.

Comment: @Nasser what do you mean to set it up as a polynomial first. Isn't equation (2) already a polynomial in all differential coefficients?

Comment: I meant to do as you did in eq(2) in order to see the degree. I was just agreeing with what you did. i.e. it is now a polynomial in differentials, and you pick the one with the highest degree on it.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you very much for the clarification and thank you all for answering.